# For which css properties it' not good to use relative values?

Tags: css

for which css properties it's not good to use relative values, always `px` will give better rendering? Even when we are making Fluid layout.

I think some properties like `border-radius` and `border-width` are give improper rendering when we use relative values.

**[Edit} Example added** http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/Fbghp/3/

Is there any information at one place about which CSS propeties doesn't support relative values and which gives inconsistent result if we use?

**Edit 2: another case**

When I use text-shadow it give improper rendering in small size see example http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/Yeg8c/1/. how to get sharp rendering

Comment: This is way, way too general a question.  There are times where it's advisable to use `px` and there are times when it's advisable to use `em` or `%` some other unit and when you use each depends upon the objectives of your design.  There is no right/wrong time that is independent of the design objective.

Comment: @jfriend00 is absolutely right, and either way this is something only you can solve--what do you think works best in the situation? Lay out the pros and cons, as lists can be helpful even with small decisions.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I think some properties don't give better result in any condition if we use relative values.

Comment: @JitendraVyas: You'll have to elaborate on `border-radius`.

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: I'm asking what you mean by "improper rendering", not what properties are improperly rendered. As far as I can tell, `border-radius` plays quite nicely with relative values: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Fbghp

Comment: he means what CSS properties that best use absolute values. say for example, what happens when you use ems on div dimensions. that's not right. it will break the layout. px in this case is better for fixed layouts or % for a fluid layout -  sort of that thought.

Comment: @BoltClock I added an example to question

Comment: @fskreuz - there are certainly design cases where it might be desirable to have a div width specified in `em` units.  As I said in my earlier comment, it all depends upon the objective of that div and how it fits into the rest of your layout.

Comment: @jfriend00 yup, i agree. but in this case, how would you define a 12.5 pixel for a border width as an effect of % or em? there could be issues of rounding off where the effects can be "fuzzy" and objects might be off by 1 or 2 pixels, and who knows what if a 50%-50% left-floated divs were there. it will drive the other div off below. it might be nice to know which are best used for the task.

Comment: @fskreuz - as I said, it depends upon the design objective.  Obviously, there are many cases for using px for div widths.  There are also cases for other units - depending upon the design.  One cannot say one type of unit is more desirable than the other without the context and objective of the design.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok, i get the point. i rest my case. XD

Comment: I don't think your text-shadow jsFiddle has anything to do with the units you chose.  You're just using too large a textshadow for a small font.  Make it small enough in any unit and it seems fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bVemX/.  Obviously, if you need fine pixel-level control over small things, use pixels.

Answer (score 4):

Per [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius), border-radius supports all expected types of units.  It appears that there was originally some confusion about how percent values should work and not all browsers implemented it or implemented it the same originally so some older browsers have different behavior than the current standard and than the current browsers.  It is now agreed that percent for border-radius means the radius should be a percent of the element's box height and box width.

From that reference on border-radius:

> percentage values
>
> - are not supported in older Chrome and Safari versions (it was fixed in Sepember 2010)
> - are buggy in Opera prior to 11.50
> - are implemented in a non-standard way prior to Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4). Both horizontal and vertical radii were relative to the width of the border box.